# How to write a function, that generates a vector recursively in Python?

Tags: python, recursion

How can I write a recursive function to generate a vector `X` of size `(1,n)` as follows, where `X_i` is the i-th entry:

```
X_1 = Z_1 * E_1
X_i = max{B_(1,i) * X_1, ... , B_((i-1),i) * X_(i-1), Z_i} * E_i,  i = 2,...,n,
```

where

```
Z = np.random.normal(0, 1,size = n)
E = np.random.lognormal(0, 1, size = n)
B = np.random.uniform(0,1,(n,n))
```

I do not have any experience with recursive functions, that is why I can not present any code with which I tried to solve this.

Comment: Why does the function have to be recursive?

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment. Have you tried writing it in pseudocode? So you can grasp the recursive concept first?

Comment: No special reason, I thought this is the way to generate this vector. If there is another way I am also happy with this.

Comment: Looks like you need to spend some time with a Python tutorial on loops and/or functions. :-)

Comment: Do you need the whole distribution or just samples from it?

Comment: @BlackBear just a vector X with samples

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with numpy, then use all the power of numpy, not just the random module ;)

And if you work with vectors, then forget about recursion and use numpy's vectorised operations. For example, np.max gives you the maximum over an axis, np.dot gives you element-wise multiplication. You also have np.prod for the product of array elements over a given axis... Those are just examples that might fit your problem well. For a full documentation, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/

Answer (score 0):

I got it, one does not need a recursion as @meowgoesthedog stated in the first comment.

```
import numpy as np

s=1000  # sample size
n=5

Z = np.random.normal(0, 1,size = (s,n))

B = np.random.uniform(0,1,(n,n))
E = np.random.lognormal(0, 1, size = (s,n))

X = np.zeros((s,n))

X[:,0] = Z[:,0]*E[:,0]

for k in range(s):
    for l in range(1,n):
        X[k,l] = max(np.max(X[k,:(l)] * B[:(l),l]), Z[k,l]) * E[k,l]
```